# text is overwritten when using multirow

Tags: tables, color, multirow

Three figures.

First, text2 is one line above textB/textC [OK]
Unfortunately, I need an extra line for text2 in the souce - therefore, textA needs a bit too much space (but i can live with that)

Now, I wanna make the background color gray instead of white
This works, if text2 is in the first line (see multirow(1).

Third, gray doesnt work, if text2 is above textB/textC - why is text2 overwritten although its color is black?
tnx!

here the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\definecolor{COLORROW}{HTML}{BEBEBE}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\footnotesize{text2}}} \\
\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize{textA}} & \footnotesize{textB} & \footnotesize{textC} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\rowcolor{COLORROW}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\footnotesize{text2}}} \\
\rowcolor{COLORROW}
\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize{textA}} & \footnotesize{textB} & \footnotesize{textC} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\rowcolor{COLORROW}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\footnotesize{text2}}} \\
\rowcolor{COLORROW}
\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize{textA}} & \footnotesize{textB} & \footnotesize{textC} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

text

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: This will of course work without the `biblatex` and `pdfpages` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpting from section 3.4 of the user guide of the `multirow` package:

> If you use `\multirow` with the `colortbl` package you have to take precautions if you
>   want to color the column that has the `\multirow` in it. The `colortbl` package works
>   by coloring each cell separately. So if you use `\multirow` with a positive `<nrows>`
>   value, `colortbl` will first color the top cell, then `\multirow` will typeset `<nrows>`
>   cells starting with this cell, and later `colortbl` will color the other cells, effectively hiding the text in that area. ...

The user guide goes on to suggest a work-around, but AFAICT the work-around doesn't apply to your setup. Instead, I suggest using two nested `tabular` environments and not use `multirow` at all.

Incidentally, do take note of the fact that `\footnotesize` is not a macro that takes an argument. Instead, it acts like a switch, i.e., its scope is through the end of the current TeX group. Writing `\footnotesize textC` is to be preferred over `\footnotesize{textC}`. If you're a stickler for detail, you might write `{\footnotesize textC}`. However, since cells in a `tabular` environment are TeX groups, there's no advantage in writing `{\footnotesize textC}` over `\footnotesize textC` in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{HTML}{BEBEBE}
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|rrr|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\footnotesize text2}} \\
\rot{textA} & \footnotesize textB & \footnotesize textC  \\
\hline
\end{tabular} --- without color, ``text2'' is visible

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\rowcolor{mygray}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\footnotesize text2 }} \\
\rowcolor{mygray}
\rot{textA} & \footnotesize textB & \footnotesize textC  \\
\end{tabular} --- with color and multirow, ``text2 is hidden''

\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\rowcolor{mygray} & & \\
\rowcolor{mygray} \rot{textA} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cc@{}}
     \rowcolor{mygray} \multicolumn{2}{c}{\footnotesize text2} \\
     \rowcolor{mygray} \footnotesize textB & \footnotesize textC  
  \end{tabular}}
\end{tabular} --- ``text2'' is visible once more

\end{document}
```

Comment: tnx for your help!

Comment: i have a second question - maybe you can answer this too :) -> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364290/text-is-overwritten-when-using-multirow-part-ii-alignment