# text is overwritten when using multirow, part ii: alignment

Tags: tables, multirow

see part i: [text is overwritten when using multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364201/text-is-overwritten-when-using-multirow)

now I want to align the header of the columns ("Abs." and "Rel."):

```
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\rowcolor{COLORROW} \rot{textA} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}cc@{}}
     \rowcolor{COLORROW} \multicolumn{2}{c}{\footnotesize text2} \\
     \rowcolor{COLORROW} \footnotesize Abs. & \footnotesize Rel.
     %\rowcolor{COLORROW} \multicolumn{1}{r}{\footnotesize Abs.} & \footnotesize Rel.
  \end{tabular}}
\\

\footnotesize{ 1} & \footnotesize{  5} & \footnotesize{ 1.00\%} \\
\footnotesize{ 2} & \footnotesize{ 10} & \footnotesize{10.03\%} \\
\footnotesize{ 3} & \footnotesize{  2} & \footnotesize{ 5.00\%} \\
\footnotesize{ 4} & \footnotesize{100} & \footnotesize{ 3.50\%} \\

\end{tabular}
```

but the alignment doesnt work, also tried a multicolumn-formatting (see %\rowcolor ...)

[image]

Comment: btw: sorry mico for using \footnotesize{...} again ;)

Comment: You have a tabular inside a multicolumn.  The columns of this tabular have nothing in common with the columns of the main tabular.  BTW, for best results, put \footnotesize INSIDE braces.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: colorrow, documentclass etc. is defined in part i, see first line

Comment: @Robert - Please post standalone, i.e., fully compilable code chunks. Asking people to navigate back and forth between web pages just to figure out background information is a sure-fire way to annoy and discourage them.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this layout, using the `S` column type from `siunitx`, if this is what you want (not sure):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize#1}} %
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\colorlet{COLORROW}{Gainsboro!70}
\usepackage{siunitx, booktabs}

    \begin{document}

{\footnotesize%
\begin{tabular}{rS[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.2]}
\rowcolor{COLORROW}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text2\rule{0pt}{4ex}} \\
     \rowcolor{COLORROW} \rot{\rlap{textA}} & {Abs.} &{Rel.\,(\%)} \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
1 & 5 & 1.00 \\
2 & 10 & 10.03 \\
3 & 2 & 5.00 \\
4 & 100 & 3.50 \\
\end{tabular}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bernhard, tnx - interesting answer, maybe i can adapt "table-format" to make it right aligned (see first figure above)

Comment: With the `S` column type, numbers are aligned by their decimal dot (or comma). The non-numeric cells (such as the column head) have to be between brackets and are centred. I was not too sure of what you want, so I did it the standard way. Did you actually want the column heads right aligned?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight variation on Bernard's solution.  I use struts to reserve enough space for the rotated text.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\definecolor{COLORROW}{HTML}{BEBEBE}

\usepackage{rotating}
\newcommand\rot[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\footnotesize#1}}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\sbox0{\rot{textA}}% measure size
\def\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{0.5\ht0}\rule[-0.5\dp0]{0pt}{0pt}}% note: local to group
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
\rowcolor{COLORROW} \mystrut & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text2} \\
\rowcolor{COLORROW} \mystrut \smash{\usebox0} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Abs.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Rel.} \\
1 & 5 & 1.00\% \\
2 & 10 & 10.03\% \\
3 & 2 & 5.00\% \\
4 & 100 & 3.50\%
\end{tabular}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]